# If $G$ has exactly $8$ elements of order $3$ ; how many subgroups of order $3$ does $G$ have ?

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a group that has exactly $8$ elements of order $3$ ; how many subgroups of order $3$ does $G$ have ??

Comment: How many elements of order $3$ are there in a group of order $3$?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Two elements

Comment: Right. And can any of those elements of order $3$ belong to two different subgroups of order $3$?

Comment: Pair elements with their inverses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subgroup of order $3$ has two elements of order $3$ and one element of order $1$ (namely the identity). Show that two subgroups of order $3$ are either identical, or have only the identity in common. Thus the $8$ elements of order $3$ must be divided amongst $4$ subgroups of order $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that a group of order $3$ is cyclic. So such a group has $\{1, g, g^{-1}\}$, where $|g| = |g^{-1}| = 3$. So this gives us four subgroups of order $3$.

Answer (score 0):

4 is the answer.

If the number of elements of order p is n,then the number of subgroups of order p is  $n/\phi(p)$,where $\phi()$ is the Euler phi function .